# Using Get-AzureAdUser is there a way to pull back all users from source "windows server ad"?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I have a directory that has about 200k users in it. I need to pull back all the users that came from on-prem AD. This of course would exclude the multiple source guest users. I have to use source because not all users have a usertype.

If there was a way to search Department not equal to null that would work as well, but it doesn't appear to be part of the odata filter standard.

```
Get-AzureADUser -Filter "Department eq ''"  | select DisplayName,`
    UserPrincipalName,Mail,creationType,AccountEnabled,Department
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get users that come from on-prem AD you could do something like this

```
 Get-AzureADUser -Filter "dirSyncEnabled eq true"
```

For selecting only a few, other operators like top can be used as well.. e.g.

```
 Get-AzureADUser -top 5 -Filter "dirSyncEnabled eq true"
```

To get all users one shot you can do

```
Get-AzureADUser -All $true -Filter "dirSyncEnabled eq true"
```

or

```
Get-AzureADUser -all $true | where-object -property DirSyncEnabled -eq "True"
```

Comment: This answer provided exactly what i needed, not sure how to mark it as such. Thank you! Now I need to figure out how to find attributes like this.. with active directory I feel like the discovery process is much similar, but that might just be me being naive.

Comment: @SeanKnox You're welcome. To figure out attributes, generally you can look at that object's documentation e.g. for User object https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity .. I should say although `dirSyncEnabled` happens to be a very special one and I have some experience with AzureAD Connect which took me in that direction.. about your question on how to mark an answer.. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Thank you for these resources! I would never have googled or clicked on "entity and complex type references"